# Understanding Lists adding/removing a value

Tags: basic4android

I'm learning lists and adding/removing. In the below code I create a list , generate a random number - and then want to permanently remove the number from the list:

```
cardsLST.AddAll(Array As Int(1,2,3,4,5))  'create the list
s = Rnd(1,6)  'generate a random number 1-5
Msgbox(s,"")  'display the randomly generated number
Msgbox(cardsLST,"")   'display the current list members
cardsLST.RemoveAt(s)   'remove the generated value from the list
Msgbox(strtCardsLST,"")   'display the updated list members
```

I can't make sense of the numbers... for example...
If I generate a 1, a 2 is removed from the list.
If I generate a 5, I get an out of bounds exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List and array indeces are zero based so your list is indexed from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

`cardsLST.AddAll(Array As Int(1,2,3,4,5))` is equivalent to the following:

```
cardsLST.insertAT(0,"1")   'cardsLST.isert(Index as int, Value as object)
cardsLST.insertAT(1,"2")
cardsLST.insertAT(2,"3")
cardsLST.insertAT(3,"4")
cardsLST.insertAT(4,"5")
```

You can use your random generator to generate index value of the card with 
`s = Rnd(0,5)` to generate a random number 0-4 so

```
cardsLST.RemoveAt(3)
```

would remove card "4"